# no flashlog.txt

Tags: logging, flex3

I have troubles with the FlashPlayer logging.

Yes, I have installed the debugging version, a mm.cfg file (content is ErrorReportingEnable=1 TraceOutputFileEnable=1) exists in my profile folder, but there is no flashlog.txt.

I am using Windows 7 (x64) and IE8 if that's important.

Answer (score 3):

A solution:

1. Install the Firebug add-on in Firefox
2. Create a log function in AS3.

The code:

```
import flash.external.ExternalInterface;

function log(msg:String):void {
    ExternalInterface.call("console.log", msg);
}
```

The above function calls the javascript console.log function. When you execute the following command from you movieclip:

```
log("I'm testing my movieclip");
```

you will see that message in your Firebug console.

Answer (score 0):

I had similar problem year or two ago on linux and solution was to create `flashlog.txt` file at default place.